# Adding Subitems to ListView with Button, using Class

Tags: c#, class, listview, button, listbox

I made a Class:

```
    class Product
{

    public string product { get; set; }
    public int aantal { get; set; }
    public double bedrag { get; set; }

}
```

In Designer I made two listboxes, a button and a listview.
When I click on an item in the 1st listbox, the selected item should go to the 2nd listbox. I have done this already (1st listbox not in the picture)
From the 2nd listbox, I should be able to get the items in the listview with all the subitems. I am having a lot of trouble to get all the items + subitems in the listview. Can someone please help me?

[Current Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDPLm.png)

This is the code I used in the form:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "H&M")
        {

            Product product1 = new Product();
            product1.product = "Jeans";
            product1.aantal = 1;
            product1.bedrag = 14.9;

            Product product2 = new Product();
            product2.product = "Sokken";
            product2.aantal = 1;
            product2.bedrag = 1.5;

            Product product3 = new Product();
            product3.product = "Schoenen";
            product3.aantal = 1;
            product3.bedrag = 24.9;

            List<string> artikelHM = new List<string>() {product1.product, product2.product, product3.product};
            listBox2.DataSource = artikelHM;
        }
```

This is what I tried with the button:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView2.Items.Add(listBox2.Text);
        listView2.Items[0].SubItems.Add(listBox2.Text);
        listView2.Items[0].SubItems.Add(listBox2.Text);
    }
```

I have not yet added anything in the listview code.

Comment: 1. In the `Product` class, create a default constructor `public Product() { }` and override the `ToString()` function to return the `product` property. 2. Bind a list of `Product` objects to the `listBox2` not a list of strings: `var artikelHM = new List<string>() {product1, product2, product3};` `listBox2.DataSource = null;` `listBox2.DataSource = artikelHM;` 3. In the `button1_Click` event, cast the selected item to a `Product` type: `var product = (Product)listBox2.SelectedItem;` and use it to create a new `ListViewItem`.